# How many permutations are the on $\mathbb{Z}_5$ such that the orbits of 2 have 3 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many permutations are the on $\mathbb{Z}_5$ such that the orbits of $2$ have $3$ elements.

It looks like there are $24$. There are $12$ such permutations where the elements outside the orbit of $2$ are fixed and a another $12$ where they permute to each other.

This one wasn't bad to make an exhaustive list but that could quickly become tiresome. How to I figure that out without making an exhaustive list? I tried looking at my book but couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the cycle representation, we know that such a permutation $\sigma$ contains a 3-cycle of the form $(2 \; a \; b)$ where $a \neq b$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5 \setminus \{2\}$.
There are thus $4 \cdot 3$ such 3-cycles, and for each such cycle we could either swap the remaining two elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ or fix them. This gives a total of $2 \cdot (4 \cdot 3)=24$ permutations.